# Create a subview overlay for an Image View in a Table View on tap

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I would like to create a subview that pops up over the `UITableView` that contains the image  of the `UIImageView` on the `cell` in full screen with an exit button in the top right corner and the `UITextView` of the `cell` on the bottom in another `cell` or `UITextView`

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TalesTableViewCell let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "imageTapped:")

    cell.tableImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

    cell.tableImage.userInteractionEnabled = true

    return cell
}

func imageTapped(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    //Code here I think

}
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following code..

```
func imageTapped(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    var overlay : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height))

    var imageView : UIImageView = UIImageView(image: (gesture.view as! UIImageView).image) // This includes your image in table view cell

    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0) // set up according to your requirements

    var doneBtn : UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)) // set up according to your requirements
    doneBtn.addTarget(self, action: "pressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    overlay.addSubview(imageView)
    overlay.addSubview(doneBtn)

    self.view.addSubview(overlay)
}

func pressed(sender: UIButton!) {

    sender.superview?.removeFromSuperview()
}
```